# Como realizar uma simples busca por estados e cidade com jquery e json

Tags: jquery, json

Esse é o meu `json` de teste e preciso, através das chaves **"ce"** e **"fortaleza"**, realizar uma busca de seus respectivos dados. No caso, a busca é feita por `AJAX` que foi submetido a um `POST` através de um formulário com dois select:

```
{
  "ce": {
    "fortaleza": [
      {
        "nome": "Teste",
        "email": "xx@xxx.com",
        "cel": "(xx) xx-xx"
      },
      {
        "nome": "Teste",
        "email": "xx@xxx.com",
        "cel": "(xx) xx-xx"
      }
    ],

    "sobral": [
      {
        "nome": "Teste",
        "email": "xx@xxx.com",
        "cel": "(xx) xx-xx"
      },
      {
        "nome": "Teste",
        "email": "xx@xxx.com",
        "cel": "(xx) xx-xx"
      }
    ]
  },
    "rn": {
    "carnaiba": [
      {
        "nome": "Teste",
        "email": "xx@xxx.com",
        "cel": "(xx) xx-xx"
      },
      {
        "nome": "Teste",
        "email": "xx@xxx.com",
        "cel": "(xx) xx-xx"
      }
    ],

    "sorisal": [
      {
        "nome": "Teste",
        "email": "xx@xxx.com",
        "cel": "(xx) xx-xx"
      },
      {
        "nome": "Teste",
        "email": "xx@xxx.com",
        "cel": "(xx) xx-xx"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Formulário com resultado exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Não tenho a mínima ideia de como fazer isso com jquery, pois sou completamente leigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) do jQuery para recuperar os dados da sua página em JSON e ai basta selecionar os dados baseado no que o usuário digitou.

Veja o exemplo

index.html

```js
// captura o evento de submit do formulário
$('#form').submit(function(event) {
 // previne que o formulário seja enviado para a página default
 event.preventDefault();

 // salva os dados do formulário em um array
 var form = $(this).serializeArray();

 // pega o estado dos dados recuperados
 var estado = form[0];

 // pega a cidade dos dados recuperados
 var cidade = form[1];

 // faz uma requisição para a página em json
 $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
  // seleciona o estado e cidade baseado no que o usuário seleciononou
  var match = data[estado.value][cidade.value];

  // faz um loop no objeto retornado
  $.each(match, function(index, element) {
   // faz algo com os dados
   console.info(element);
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form">
  <div>
   <label for="estado">Estado</label>
   <select id="estado" name="estado">
    <option value="ce">Ceará</option>
    <option value="outro">Outras opções</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div>
   <label for="cidade">Cidade</label>
   <select id="cidade" name="cidade">
    <option value="fortaleza">Fortaleza</option>
    <option value="outro">Outras opções</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

O `data.json` tem o mesmo conteúdo que você forneceu na postagem..

Comment: Perfeito! Como faço para, quando houver uma nova busca, limpar a anterior? Obrigado.

Comment: O que seria "limpar" no caso? Voltar os selects ao estado inicial?

Comment: Exatamente. Ele limpa o anterior e consulta um novo. Isso tudo após o clique no submit. Outro problema que fica se repetindo. Queria que não ouvesse uma segunda consulta no mesmo `estado+cidade`, mas somente `estado+outra cidade`.

Comment: Para resetar um select para setar o index dele para -1 (ou qualquer outro index que quiser), assim: `$('select').prop('selectedIndex', -1);` se preferir pode ainda inserir um input type reset e simular um clique nele. E para desabilitar o select vai depender da situação, você quer que após atualizar a página ele possa selecionar tudo novamente? Basta usar isso `$('select option').attr('disabled','disabled');` Caso contrário pode trabalhar com `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, etc

Answer (score 1):

Você pode obter o arquivo JSON por meio do método `$.getJSON(path)`, que te retorna uma Promise. Com base nessa Promise, você pode verificar os dados contidos no arquivo, se o mesmo foi recuperado com sucesso.

Como o arquivo já vem convertido para um objeto JS, você pode acessar as propriedades do mesmo, que contem os dados que você quer. Segue código abaixo.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';

    var promiseDados = $.getJSON('dados.json'),
        chaveEstado = 'ce',
        chaveCidade = 'fortaleza';

    promiseDados.done(function (dados) {
        var pessoas = dados[chaveEstado][chaveCidade];

        pessoas.forEach(function (pessoa, index) {
            var div = $('<div></div>');

            div.append('<span>PESSOA ' + (index + 1) + '</span>');

            Object.keys(pessoa).forEach(function (key) {
                div.append('<div>' + pessoa[key] + '</div>');
            });

            $('body').append(div);
        });
    });

    promiseDados.fail(function (error) {
        console.log('Falha ao obter JSON', error);
    });
});
```